# update data in Arrays and loops

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

```
               $buy_amount = 50;                  

                $amount[0] = 100;
                $amount[1] = 150;
                $amount[2] = 50;

                $test;

                $i = $buy_amount;
                $arrlength = count($amount);

                for ($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {

                   $test = $amount[$x] - $i;
                    if ($amount[$x] != $test) {
                        $i = $test;
                        echo $test;
                        echo '<br/>';
                    }  
                }
```

What I need to do is if i send `$buy_amount = 50` result need to be subtract like this

Example:

```
    $amount[0] = 50;
    $amount[1] = 150;
    $amount[2] = 50;
```

if i send `$buy_amount = 150` result need to be subtract like this

Example:

```
            $amount[0] = 0;
            $amount[1] = 100;
            $amount[2] = 50;
```

In here what i need to do first subtract from first element and go to other and subtact from that if `buy_amount` left more go to other element like wise

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: So, you want to update `$amount` based on the value of `$buy_amount`?  What's your criteria?

Comment: i need to reduce from array. no errors

Comment: @Amalprasad: What do you mean "reduce from array"?  Do you just want so subtract a certain value from each element?

Comment: yes rocket i need to do that

Comment: be more specific...code that doesn't work is not a replacement for explanation of what you want it to do

Comment: need to subtract certain value from each element of the array any one can help me how to do that? plz see the examples

Comment: inside your loop $amount[$x] = $amount[$x] - $buy_amount. you're never assigning new values to your array items in your current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for

```
$amount[0] = 100;
$amount[1] = 150;
$amount[2] = 50;

$buy_amount = 250; // Change to whatever you want

$amount = array_map(
          function ($mValue) use (&$buy_amount)
          {

             if($buy_amount >= $mValue){

                $buy_amount = $buy_amount - $mValue;
                return 0;
             }

             $sReturnValue = $mValue - $buy_amount;
             $buy_amount = 0;

             return $sReturnValue;

          }
          ,$amount);

var_dump($amount);
```

Comment: sanjuna plz see examples. This code subtract from all elements isnt it?

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you need logically?

Comment: when i add buy_amount = 200 subtract that amount from each element in array.  if 1st element got 100, subtract that and go to other element and subtract what is left in that buy_amount. array is updated using database i didnt put all code just put some values to array.

Comment: Hey Sorry, Didn't understand your question initially. Edited the code now. have a look to see if this is what you mean